# knockout data-bind with a function call

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to call a function in data-bind but nothing seems to work.

Here is my scenario:

```
function ViewModel() {

  this.Products = ko.observableArray([]);

  this.FormatUrl = function (url) {
     ...
     return ...
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Products">

 ...
    <td><div data-bind="attr:{style: images.length > 0 ? 'background-image:url($root.FormatUrl(images[0]));' : ''}" /></td>

 ...
</tbody>
```

I also tried with quotes `'$root.Format..'` and got an `SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings. Message: Unexpected identifier`

What is the correct way to call my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're mixing a string with a function call:

```
'background-image:url($root.FormatUrl(images[0]));'
```

You either need to construct it thusly:

```
'background-image:url(' + $root.FormatUrl(images[0]) + ');'
```

Or perhaps return the whole string from your `FormatUrl` function, rather than concatenating in your view.